# Laravel 6 api 401 Unauthorized from ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

**Laravel 6**
Ajax
MY api route:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:api'])->group(function(){
   Route::resource('academic_year','AcademicYear\AcademicYearController')->except(['create', 'edit']);
}
```

There ajax request and still get unauthorized this my request:

```
var token = "{{Auth()->user()->api_token}}";
    console.log('token: '+token);
    var basicData = {
      'headers': {
          'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+token,
          'Accept' : 'application/json',
      },
      '_token': "{{csrf_token()}}"
    };
    var data = basicData;
    data['title'] = $('input.academic-title').val();
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
      url: "{{route('academic_year.index')}}",
      method: 'POST',
      datatype: 'application/json',
      data: basicData,
      success: function(data, status, xhr){
       console.log(status);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, message){
        console.log(status);
      },
    });
```

I don't know where the problem!!

Comment: You may forget to use auth middleware to this route..Please share your route of academic_year.index

Comment: try to add headers as parameter, not as data $.ajax({headers: {}, data: basicData });

Comment: @ValenTin I try to do as you say but the same result

Comment: @Sehdev                                                                  
          Route::middleware(['auth:api'])->group(function(){ Route::resource('academic_year','AcademicYear\AcademicYearController')->except(['create', 'edit']);}

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is sending token with header. can you try like this way to set token with header

```html
var token = "{{Auth()->user()->api_token}}";
    var basicData = {
      '_token': "{{csrf_token()}}"
    };
    var data = basicData;
    data['title'] = $('input.academic-title').val();
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
      url: "{{route('academic_year.index')}}",
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {"Authorization": 'Bearer '+token,'Accept' : 'application/json'}
      datatype: 'application/json',
      data: basicData,
      success: function(data, status, xhr){
       console.log(status);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, message){
        console.log(status);
      },
    });
```